# Random Error in Discord.py -- Can't find a fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Magussi\PycharmProjects\Project_1\DripMaster.py", line 10, in <module>
        client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';')
      File "C:\Users\Magussi\PycharmProjects\Project_1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1015, in __init__
        super().__init__(command_prefix, help_command, description, options)
    TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

```py
    import random
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import time
    
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.members = True
    
    token = 'hehe'
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';')
    client.remove_command('help')
```

I've tried re-generating the Token. And I've been going around in discord servers trying to find answers to this issue and I'm unable to find the fix. Everything was working for 2 days and then all of a sudden it just stopped working... Any fix to this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of discord.py rewrite.

You are not using the members intent. This can be fixed by using `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';', intents=intents)`

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Same line.

Comment: Uninstall discord.py and anything that says discord and reinstall it using pip

Comment: Uhm... I got a ton of errors https://pastebin.com/RwZBp1d1

Comment: @Magussi make sure you enable privilege intents in the developer panel for the bot. It's located in the bot section